# Change in map's parent state automatically unspiderfies cluster in react-leaflet-markercluster

Tags: javascript, leaflet, react-leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am using [react-leaflet-markercluster](https://github.com/yuzhva/react-leaflet-markercluster) to cluster some markers in a react-leaflet application.  A crucial part of my application is that when a user clicks a map marker, the marker should be highlighted (i.e. update its icon), as well as communicate with more global state to show some information about that marker.  This works.  However, when applying the same logic from within a marker cluster, I have an issue.

When clicking a cluster, the markers spiderfy, as desired.  But then when clicking one of the individual markers in the cluster, state is udpated to reflect that this marker should be highlighted.  However, the update in state seems to reset the cluster, and automatically unspiderfy the cluster.  A quick visual:

[image]

[Codesandbox demonstrating the issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-markercluster-state-issue-pil0b3?file=/src/App.js)

Even if the state update does not originate from within the map itself (as in the case of clicking the buttons on the bottom), if the the MapContainer is in the component with the state update (which it must be, as the markers need to react to the state update), the cluster closes.

The react-leaflet-markercluster repo is deprecated.  But [the source code](https://github.com/yuzhva/react-leaflet-markercluster/blob/master/src/react-leaflet-markercluster.js) is relatively short and simple:

```
const MarkerClusterGroup = createPathComponent(
  ({ children: _c, ...props }, ctx) => {
    const clusterProps = {};
    const clusterEvents = {};

    // Splitting props and events to different objects
    Object.entries(props).forEach(([propName, prop]) =>
      propName.startsWith('on')
        ? (clusterEvents[propName] = prop)
        : (clusterProps[propName] = prop)
    );

    // Creating markerClusterGroup Leaflet element
    const markerClusterGroup = new L.markerClusterGroup(clusterProps);

    // Initializing event listeners
    Object.entries(clusterEvents).forEach(([eventAsProp, callback]) => {
      const clusterEvent = `cluster${eventAsProp.substring(2).toLowerCase()}`;
      markerClusterGroup.on(clusterEvent, callback);
    });

    return {
      instance: markerClusterGroup,
      context: { ...ctx, layerContainer: markerClusterGroup },
    };
  }
);

export default MarkerClusterGroup;
```

I have written a fair number of custom react-leaflet components myself.  My understanding was that react-leaflet does a good job of not reacting to state updates, but rather letting the underlying leaflet methods take over.  This issue does not seem present in a vanilla leaflet-markercluster example, as there is no state to worry about.  What is wrong with the source code there, and how might I fix it, so avoid having the cluster unspiderfy when a marker is clicked on, and rather, just turn the marker green in its spiderfied state?

Comment: I had a similar issue, I ended up using memo on all child markers. Did some caveman debugging by removing on dependency one by one from the useMemo dependency array. Ended up being a function that was passed down as a function that triggered the rerender since it was seen as a new function all the time.